# how can i seperate and display time and date from a string

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm using curl to send XML data and get a response back from the API server

my date string is in this format 201810011450

I would like to separate my date and time from this string into two separate fields

$date and $time

I have tried using the strtotime but it does not show me the right output.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 2):

Make a DateTme object

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi','201810011450');
```

And then convert it to the format, you want

```
echo $dt->format('r'); // Mon, 01 Oct 2018 14:50:00 -0400
```

For example,

```
$date = $dt->format('Ymd'); 
$time = $dt->format('Hi');
```